# Corruption of NSManagedObject-derived objects when property is accessed

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a class that at some point gets a bunch of data with a Core Data fetch and then inserts the objects, created in the usual Core Data way in XCode and therefore derived from `NSManagedObject`, into an `NSMutableSet`. Depending on how things work out, some of these objects might end up in several other sets. So far, so good.

But then the following happens:

```
NSMutableArray* anArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init;
[currentResults minus:previousResults]; // both are NSMutableSets
for(MyObject* obj in currentResults)
{
   [anArray addObject:[createAnnoFromMyObject:obj]]; // nastiness happens here
}
```

All `createAnnoFromMyObj:` does is pull data out of `obj` and return a object that implements `MKAnnotation`.

The problem is that although I get an array of usable annotations, `currentResults`, `previousResults`, and any other objects that references any of the `MyObject`s that were touched by `createAnnoFromMyObject:` end up getting trashed.

By trashed I mean that trying to access them results in an exception along the lines of

```
-[MyObject beginningOfDocument]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...
```

The same happens when trying to view any of these collections in the debugger pane with the `po` command.

We tried regenerating `MyObject` in Core Data but no luck. There is very little mention of this `beginningOfDocument` selector on Google and we have no idea what coudl be wrong. Although we have a workaround that will probably eliminate this issue, it would be really nice to know what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this specific unrecognized selector problem - that `beginningOfDocument` was being called on my (subclass of) `NSManagedObject` instance in iOS5.x. The problem looks to be fixed in iOS6 though. I also verified that NSZombies gave me nothing, even though it certainly seemed like the right intuition.

The unrecognized selector exception was thrown during a `valueForKey` lookup on our managed object, so it's worth looking at the stack trace to see if this is where the exception is thrown for you as well.

In our case, the "broken" key was `fullText`, the name of one of our attributes. Changing the name eliminated the problem. My guess is that the name caused an error in the underlying sqlite query (I didn't think fulltext was a keyword, but maybe for the full text searching in sqlite?), and perhaps the query arguments are better sanitized in iOS6.

You can find out what key/attribute name is broken with this little cheat: Override your `valueForKey:` method temporarily to NSLog and then just call the superclass version and return it. Even though the docs say not to override it (which we're only doing for a moment to find the offending attribute), this is ok since we're just overriding and then calling the superclass implementation.

```
// Don't forget to remove me after the bug is fixed!
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"Finding value for key: %@", key);
    return [super valueForKey:key];
}
```

Then when you run again, you'll see the last call to `valueForKey:` before the crash and know what attribute name is broken.

If you're still having trouble sorting out which was the unsuccessful lookup, you could go with the more verbose:

```
// Don't forget to remove me after the bug is fixed!
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"Finding value for key: %@", key);
    id retVal = [super valueForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Success for key: %@", key); // or print retVal for fun
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Congrats on tracking that down. `fullText` was all over the place in our Core Data model. Unfortunately, it's going to be hard to verify since that revision never got committed because of the crashes, but based on your data, it really looks like the field name was the issue. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Awesome - I'm glad the post at least helps resolve some mystery! Thanks for marking it.

Comment: Thanks Kelly for this post. We had exactly the same `unrecognized selector` crash with the same `beginningOfDocument` method call. This crash happened inside the RestKit framework that we use. So it took some time to figure out that is has something to do with KVC and iOS5 and not with RestKit. Thanks to your post we got pointed into the right direction and found a `fullText` in our CoreData model as well. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your MyObject is being dealloced.  I would guess you're using ARC in this case, and that you don't have anything holding on to the MyObject object (check that the NSSets the object is in are also being held somehow).  Which means it will be released at the end of the current run loop and you'll see the error you're getting.

You could run Zombies in Instruments to prove this theory.

Comment: Yeah, I am using ARC. I don't think it's a case of the MyObjects being deallocated because there is at any given time at least one reference to each of them. The sets are proporties of the class, so it's pretty unlikely they are getting deallocated. Also, Instruments does not report any issues.

Comment: You're not passing the managed objects between classes right? Or trying to use the same object with a moc other than the one that created it?

Comment: I'm getting the MyObjects from another class, but it's just a simple case of fetch and return. I haven't run into any warnings about doing this. And no Moc mixing either.